# SQL UNION but fill in NULL value

Tags: sql, select, null, union

I have two tables and a section of Table1 looks something like this

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A100 | Bob | Odenkirk | Male | 30 |
| A101 | Jon | Jones | NULL | 36 |

Table2 looks similar but contains a duplicate entry with some varying amount of missing/available information, i.e.,

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A101 | Jon | Jones | Male | NULL |
| A103 | Angelina | Jolie | Female | 40 |

I'm fairly new to SQL and I initially tried

```sql
 SELECT * 
   FROM Table1
  UNION 
 SELECT *
   FROM Table2
```

But obviously, the A101 row has different NULL values so it doesn't get treated as duplicates and I get:

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A100 | Bob | Odenkirk | Male | 30 |
| A101 | Jon | Jones | NULL | 36 |
| A101 | Jon | Jones | Male | NULL |
| A103 | Angelina | Jolie | Female | 40 |

Is there a general way (i.e. if the table is large and not sure which values might be missing from Table1 or Table2) to somehow "fill in" the NULL values and get the following **target output**:

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A100 | Bob | Odenkirk | Male | 36 |
| A101 | Jon | Jones | Male | 30 |
| A103 | Angelina | Jolie | Female | 40 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can never have "competing" values (i.e., both tables either have the same value or one of them has a `null`), you could `union all` the two queries, and then group by the `EmployeeID` and use `max` to get the present values and ignore `null`s:

```sql
SELECT   EmployeeID, MAX(FirstName), MAX(LastName), MAX(Gender), MAX(Age)
FROM     (SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Age
          FROM   Table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Age
          FROM   Table2) T
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_full_outer_join.asp) and [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) function

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.EmployeeID, t2.EmployeeID), 
       COALESCE(t1.FirstName, t2.FirstName) AS FirstName,
       COALESCE(t1.LastName, t2.LastName) AS LastName,
       COALESCE(t1.Gender, t2.Gender) AS Gender,
       COALESCE(t1.Age, t2.Age) AS Age,  
FROM Table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
```

If your DBMS does not support FULL OUTER JOIN, you could try to use UNION and COALESE function.

```
-- Retrieve all employees in Table1, then fill in NULL value using COALESCE function if it's exists in Table2
SELECT t1.EmployeeID, 
       COALESCE(t1.FirstName, t2.FirstName) AS FirstName,
       COALESCE(t1.LastName, t2.LastName) AS LastName,
       COALESCE(t1.Gender, t2.Gender) AS Gender,
       COALESCE(t1.Age, t2.Age) AS Age,  
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID  

UNION ALL  

-- Retrieve the rest employees, which is existed in Table 2, but is not existed in Table1 
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
     FROM Table1 t1
     WHERE t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID)
```